# How do I expand all and collapse all using dynatree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree

I am using dynatree and would like to have "open all" and "close all" links above the tree.  How do I do this using a link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

There's an example of expanding all nodes [in the documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h8.4.7).  Use the `.visit()` method and call `.expand()` on each node:

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){
    node.expand(true);
});
```

Pass `false` to collapse each node.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the API for it

I got this from the API example

```
<a href="#" id="btnCollapseAll">Collapse All </a>

<a href="#" id="btnExpandAll">Expand All </a>

$("#btnCollapseAll").click(function(){
      $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){
        node.expand(false);
      });
      return false;
    });
    $("#btnExpandAll").click(function(){
      $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){
        node.expand(true);
      });
      return false;
    });
```